# PostgreSQL: Count from x to y

Tags: postgresql

How do I count in PostgreSQL from X to Y where X and Y come from table fields.

Similar to how a for loop works.

I tried to use ranges.

Comment: What have you tried?
You must give us more

Comment: Have a look at ‘generate_series( 3, 10 )’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5ac1b40cbbbdd71262307a38a90aa609)

It is not quiet clear what your data looks like:

A: You have one table with two columns x and y and exactly one row:

```
x | y
--+--
2 | 5
```

B: You have one table with two columns x and y and more than one row:

```
x | y
--+--
2 | 5
3 |10
```

It's not quiet clear what you mean with "count":

I.: You want one row per element:

```
count
-----
2
3
4
5
```

II.: You want an array of all elements:

```
count
-----
{2,3,4,5}
```

---

**A.I: You have a table with two columns x and y with exactly one row and want one row per element:**

```
SELECT generate_series(x, y)
FROM values;
```

Result as seen in I. above

**B.I: You have many rows:**

Same query, result is the union of the generated rows:

```
count
-----
2
3
4
5
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

**A.II: One row, want an array:**

You have to group your generated series

```
SELECT array_agg(gs)
FROM (
    SELECT x, generate_series(x, y) as gs
    FROM values
) s
GROUP BY x
```

Result as seen in II.

**B.II: Many rows, want an array:**

Same query, result looks like:

```
count
------------------
{2,3,4,5}
{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```